# side scrolling not working on android

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an issue with my application where side scrolling is not working on Android, but it works fine in browser and in ios.

I have multiple rows that you can select drink options. The user scrolls through the options and chooses 1. If you want a visual representation to get a better idea, https://cloudup.com/cOpnPk5zXnR

In browser and ios, you can scroll through and pick one, but in android it opens up the side menu without scrolling through the options, https://cloudup.com/cKPwT8zhtZK

Here is a skimmed down example of what I'm doing.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-scroll direction="x">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="min-width:35%;">hello</div>
      <div style="min-width:35%;">this</div>
      <div style="min-width:35%;">should</div>
      <div style="min-width:35%;">be</div>
      <div style="min-width:35%;">scrollable</div>
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

One clue I've found is that if you apply `overflow-x: hidden;` to the .row, it acts like it does in android. Maybe ionic is adding something to android with ion-scroll that has a bug side-effect, but I can't seem to find anything on that.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
ios-deploy version: 1.8.5
ios-sim version: 5.0.7
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.10.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow-x: scroll;` to `.row`

Comment: just tried applying that directly and has the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer on a [github issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5139). putting `overflow-scroll="false"` on the ion-scroll element worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `edge-drag-threshold` property of `ionSideMenuContent` to limit the sliding in of the side menu only when swiped from a certain pixels from the border.

Source: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenuContent/